# Optimize annotated query in Django

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I'm trying to convert this simple SQL query into something Django can handle:

```
SELECT *
FROM location AS a
WHERE a.travel_distance = (
    SELECT MAX(travel_distance)
    FROM location AS b
    WHERE b.person_id = a.person_id
)
ORDER BY a.travel_distance DESC
```

What this basically does is fetching all traveled locations and select only the rows that contain the maximum travel distance.

This is what i got so far:

```
travels = Location.objects.filter(pk__in=Location.objects.order_by().values('person_id').annotate(max_id=Max('id')).values('max_id')).order_by('travel_distance')[::-1]
```

Although the results match each other. It takes a whole lot longer for the second method to return results.

Is there anyway I can rewrite this query, so it becomes faster?

Comment: Also, can you double-check your query as I don't think it returns the rows with the maximum travel distance. Your annotating with the Max('id'), plus the location pk's returned actually correspond to person IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the maximum distance travelled for each person. Assuming there is a Person model, perhaps ask from the other direction. Something like:

```
Person.objects.values('id').annotate(max_distance=Max('location__travel_distance'))
```

I haven't tested this since I don't have an equivalent data schema handy, but does this work for you?

Comment: How can i obtain other information from the location table in this query (i.e. name, latitude, longitude, ...)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can get that info using this approach. Very interesting question. I think the issue is that Django doesn't allow annotate + distinct. I believe you may be stuck with SQL

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this works? Something like:

```
select max(id), sum(travel_distance) from table group by person_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for a way to optimize the Django query, not the SQL query